# Java multi dimension array/ printing null values

Tags: java

This is from an array with 10 rows 4 columns. How do I get the if to keep the null values from printing to screen

```
      for(int j = 0; j < calculation[i].length; j++)
        if (calculation[i] != null)<-------- this does nothing, however if I change it to == null nothing prints to screen
      System.out.print(calculation[i][j] + " \t");
      System.out.print("\n");
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked...I feel stupid now...thanks again

Comment: -1 for not showing the declaration of `calculation`.

Comment: I feel like you shouldn't use System.out.print("\n") but rather System.out.println(""). Won't the newline characters vary from system to system? Shouldn't you just use the builtin println?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`calculation[i]` may not be null but `calculation[i][j]` could be.

Change your code to:

```
if (calculation[i][j] != null) 
      {
   //Your code.
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will print the entire array for you except for the null values.

```
  for(int i = 0; i < calculation.length; i++)
    {
      for(int j = 0; j < calculation[i].length; j++)
      {
        if(calculation[i][j] != null)
           System.out.println(calculation[i][j] + "\t");
      }
      System.out.println("");
    }
```